# segmentation fault in array search C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, char, segmentation-fault

I have this program that receives a char array with a number of messages bounded by tags. These "tags" are a sequence of chars located randomly within the char array.

Here is an example: given a char array: `{'a','s','t','1','m','s','g','e','x','1','r','s','t','1','s','t','1','s','s','g','e','x','1','z'};`. the tag `"st1"` indicates the beginning of a message which contains every char until a sequence of `"ex1"` is found, which is a tag for the end of the message, and it keeps searching the array for the next sequence of "st1" indicating the beginning of a new message. In this example, the messages are: `"msg"`,and`"st1ssg"`.

Here is my program - I keep getting a segmentation fault:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char array[] = {'a','s','t','1','m','s','g','e','x','1','r','s','t','1','s','t','1','s','s','g','e','x','1','z'};
    int state = 0;
    int found = 0;
    int i,j;
    int msgStartIndex;
    int msgEndIndex;
    while(array[i]){
        if((array[i] == 's' && state == 0) || (array[i] == 't' && state == 1) || (array[i] == '1' && state == 2) ){
            state++;
            if(!found && state == 3){
                msgStartIndex = i+1;
                found = 1;
            }
        }
        else if(!found && (array[i] = 't' && state == 2))
            state = 2;
        else if(!found)
            state = 0; 
        if((array[i] == 'e' && state == 3) || (array[i] == 'x' && state == 2) || (array[i] == '1' && state == 1) ){
            state--;
            if(found && state == 0){
                found = 0;
                msgEndIndex = i-3;
                for(j=msgStartIndex; j < msgEndIndex+1; j++)
                    printf("%c",array[j]);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        else if(found && (array[i] == 'e' ) && (state == 2 || state == 1))
            state = 2;
        else if(found)
            state = 3;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(!found && (array[i] = 't' && state == 2))` this condition violates [EXP45-C. Do not perform assignments in selection statements - CERT C Coding Standard - CERT Secure Coding Standards](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/EXP45-C.+Do+not+perform+assignments+in+selection+statements)

Answer (score 2):

You never bothered initializing your loop counter:

```
int i,j;

while(array[i]){
```

so you just start using whatever random garbage is in `i` to begin with. If that garbage happens to be bigger than the length of the array, boom goes your program.

Comment: oh true, i initialized i to 0, it works but the program fails because the array is not null terminated?

Comment: you also have `else if(!found && (array[i] = 't'` - assignment in an `if` test is usually a sign of a bug... perhaps it should be `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Variable I was notr initialized and moreover the array is not zero-terminated.

```
int i,j;
/...
while(array[i]){
```

So the loop has undefined behavior.

You could keep a string in the array and use standard function `strstr` declared in header `<string.h>` to find the starting and ending tags.